# Queryable django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there any admin panel in django that is queryable. I mean a django admin panel in which I can write my `SQL` queries.

Comment: read about the djangos admin page, you'll definitely find a solution that fits for you

Comment: I read but did not find anything relevant. Can you provide links to it.

Comment: Django admin gets used for a lot more than it was designed for - it is meant for adding initial data to the database. You would probably be better writing a custom view as its not something that you would expect to see in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

There's a build in `ModelAdmin` which gives you the opportunity to add [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) and [search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) arguments, like a SQL query.

If you want to create a raw SQL Query you are also able to add a [Admin action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/), which allows you to call every function you want to call.